# ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

I have xml file `abc.xml` in `\\192.168.1.71\err_log`

I did below steps and getting error:

```
create directory XMLDIR2 as '\\192.168.1.71\err_log';

GRANT ALL ON DIRECTORY xmldir2 TO PUBLIC;

INSERT INTO example2
VALUES ( xmltype (
           bfilename('XMLDIR2', 'abc.xml'),
           nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')
         )
       );
```

Getting below error:

```
ERROR at line 4: ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 296 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: try opening that file from OS as oracle user

Comment: I am using windows server

Comment: ah, I just realized `\\192.168.1.71\err_log` is a samba share. Try mapping the disk to windows. I don't think Oracle bfilename works with samba addresing